# Exception messages and event logging - which tense to use?

Tags: logging, coding-style

Do you have best practices regarding to which tense to use in message when you're coding exception-throwing or message-logging code: `"Could not acquire connection from DataSource"` versus `"Can not acquire connection from DataSource"`?

Comment: Exception message tells you what went wrong, therefore use past tense.

Comment: @CodeART this is from the perspective of developer when he noticed that something happen. But when you actually do looking into your log file afterwards, you mentally recovering code flow (as if it was a tape) and see messages and operate in present tense ("INFO: setting up data source", "WARN: seems that JNDI name is messed up", "SEVERE: can not create dataSource object", "SEVERE: can/could not acquire connection from DataSource: can not create dataSource object")

Comment: Question is about exceptions and not log files. If it's a debug message, then you may use present tense. For example: "Retrieving orders for customer XXX". Exception on the other hand indicates that some action was invoked and it failed to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like to use present tense when the error/exception-generating code is the "root cause" of the problem, and past tense when I'm merely repackaging an error/exception from a lower layer of code.

For example, when our frontend makes a request to our backend, the backend may return an error message "Cannot connect to database", and the frontend will throw "Failed to retrieve your widgets because: Cannot connect to database".

---

In general, the only "best practices" in regards to exception/error wording are to make it as clear, unambiguous, non-misleading and consistent as possible. In my opinion the tense convention I just described fits those criteria the best, but there are probably other equally valid conventions.

Answer (score 3):

I think past tense is a safer bet. In your example:

1) "Could not acquire connection from DataSource" - an attempt was made, failed, situation could've changed since then.

2) "Can not acquire connection from DataSource" - an attempt was made, failed, it's 100% certain that situation is still the same.

Also which tense would you pick for a timeout error?

"Timed out while acquiring connection..."

vs

"Timing out while acquiring connection..."

PS: I would be more worried about including all the helpful details, e.g.: "Could not acquire connection from DataSource '[name of server, name of database]' at [date and time] for user [username]."